# Условное появление аттрибута работает в React, но не работает в Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Почему в `Next.js` отмеченная строка при `false` отображается в html, как `data-text-btn-active="false"`? Вместо того, чтобы не отображаться вовсе? Это `boolean` значение.

Я только что в реакте делал тоже самое и все предсказуемо отрабатывает (атрибут просто не появляется в html). Это же фреймворк на базе реакта? Или я что-то не так делаю?

```
const TextButton: React.FC<TextButtonProps> = ({ thisSlide, currentSlide }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const onTextBtnClick = () => {
    setIsActive((b) => !b);
  };

  return (
    <button
      onClick={onTextBtnClick}
      className={s.textBtn}
      data-text-btn-active={isActive ? true : false} // ЭТА СТРОКА
      aria-label={`Show / hide entire message.`}
      aria-pressed={isActive ? "true" : "false"}></button>
  );
};
```

Comment: _Я только что в реакте делал тоже самое и все предсказуемо отрабатывает_ - в реакте, для `data-*` атрибутов сделано тоже самое - boolean значения остаются в разметке. Сделай запускаемый пример, в котором видно, что твой код работает именно так как ты говоришь

Comment: @Grundy, да, для `aria-*` и для `data-*` boolean просто в строку превращается, буду знать, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В React и Next.js, преобразование значений в атрибутах HTML может происходить несколько иначе, чем в чистом JavaScript или HTML. В данном случае, даже если `isActive` является булевым значением `true` или `false`, React преобразует его в соответствующую строку при рендеринге.

Если вам необходимо, чтобы атрибут вообще не появлялся в HTML, когда `isActive` равен `false`, вам следует использовать логический оператор `&&` или условный оператор.

Вот пример, как это можно сделать:

```
const TextButton: React.FC<TextButtonProps> = ({ thisSlide, currentSlide }) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = React.useState(false);

  const onTextBtnClick = () => {
    setIsActive((prev) => !prev);
  };

  const buttonProps = {
    onClick: onTextBtnClick,
    className: s.textBtn,
    "aria-label": "Show / hide entire message.",
    "aria-pressed": isActive ? "true" : "false",
  };

  if (isActive) {
    buttonProps["data-text-btn-active"] = true;
  }

  return <button {...buttonProps}></button>;
};
```

В этом примере мы создаем объект `buttonProps`, который содержит все свойства кнопки. Затем мы проверяем, активно ли состояние (`isActive`), и если да, добавляем свойство `data-text-btn-active` к объекту `buttonProps`. Наконец, мы передаем этот объект как пропсы для кнопки.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Comment: @Akniyet Maratov, Спасибо